# Are there any equivalents to the nano blitz in Madden 10?

Tags: cheats, madden-10

I have used the "nano blitz" on several occasions and it works almost everytime. Do any other plays in Madden 10 exist that allow you to exploit the way offensive lineman pick up computer players?

Comment: Can you, erm, translate that to English?

Comment: @badp: A "nano blitz" is basically a glitch (but it's not really a glitch), that allows you to get extreme amounts of pressure on the QB by overloading the line with blitzers. It is so effective that in most cases you can even throw the ball from under center and sometimes can't even hand the ball off. Thus the name nano because it allows you to tackle the QB in a matter of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Quarter's Prevent Defense never fails.

1. Go into Quarter's Defense.
2. Go to Prevent.
3. Press Triangle or Y and Press the Coverage.

That's the most annoying defense I know of, and is sure to make your opponents quite mad.